# FxCop rule list subset for ASP.NET web application

Tags: fxcop

We are in the process of integrating FxCop with VS 2010 professional for code analysis using the FxCop Integration VS Extension. We have seen that with all the default rule sets that are configured in FxCop, we are getting a whole bunch of points reported which are nice to have but not necessarily in strict violation of best practices or in most of the cases can be done without. Is there any list of rules, essentially a subset of all the rules in FxCop, which people are generally using to do code analysis for web based projects that can be considered as must have. We googled lightly but could not get a singular(discussions about ignoring specific rules based on individual choices are spread out all over the web) resource which lists out the preferred subset of rules which the community is generally following for web based asp.net/C# projects.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am using this using TeamCity Integration but rules should be same. Try with below once:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FxCopProject Version="1.36" Name="testApplication">
 <ProjectOptions>
  <SharedProject>True</SharedProject>
  <Stylesheet Apply="False">\tools\fxcop\Xml\FxCopReport.xsl</Stylesheet>
  <SaveMessages>
   <Project Status="Excluded" NewOnly="False" />
   <Report Status="Active" NewOnly="False" />
  </SaveMessages>
  <ProjectFile Compress="True" DefaultTargetCheck="True" DefaultRuleCheck="True" SaveByRuleGroup="" Deterministic="True" />
  <EnableMultithreadedLoad>True</EnableMultithreadedLoad>
  <EnableMultithreadedAnalysis>True</EnableMultithreadedAnalysis>
  <SourceLookup>True</SourceLookup>
  <AnalysisExceptionsThreshold>10</AnalysisExceptionsThreshold>
  <RuleExceptionsThreshold>1</RuleExceptionsThreshold>
  <Spelling Locale="en-GB" />
  <OverrideRuleVisibilities>False</OverrideRuleVisibilities>
  <CustomDictionaries SearchFxCopDir="True" SearchUserProfile="True" SearchProjectDir="True" />
  <SearchGlobalAssemblyCache>False</SearchGlobalAssemblyCache>
  <DeadlockDetectionTimeout>120</DeadlockDetectionTimeout>
  <IgnoreGeneratedCode>False</IgnoreGeneratedCode>
 </ProjectOptions>
 <Targets>
    <Target Name="$(ProjectDir)/../../solution/PrecompiledWeb/application/bin/App_Code.dll" Analyze="True" AnalyzeAllChildren="True" />
 </Targets>
 <Rules>
  <RuleFiles>
   <RuleFile Name="$(FxCopDir)\Rules\DesignRules.dll" Enabled="True" AllRulesEnabled="True" />
   <RuleFile Name="$(FxCopDir)\Rules\GlobalizationRules.dll" Enabled="True" AllRulesEnabled="True" />
   <RuleFile Name="$(FxCopDir)\Rules\InteroperabilityRules.dll" Enabled="True" AllRulesEnabled="True" />
   <RuleFile Name="$(FxCopDir)\Rules\MobilityRules.dll" Enabled="True" AllRulesEnabled="True" />
   <RuleFile Name="$(FxCopDir)\Rules\NamingRules.dll" Enabled="True" AllRulesEnabled="True" />
   <RuleFile Name="$(FxCopDir)\Rules\PerformanceRules.dll" Enabled="True" AllRulesEnabled="True" />
   <RuleFile Name="$(FxCopDir)\Rules\PortabilityRules.dll" Enabled="True" AllRulesEnabled="True" />
   <RuleFile Name="$(FxCopDir)\Rules\SecurityRules.dll" Enabled="True" AllRulesEnabled="True" />
   <RuleFile Name="$(FxCopDir)\Rules\UsageRules.dll" Enabled="True" AllRulesEnabled="True" />
  </RuleFiles>
  <Groups />
  <Settings />
 </Rules>
 <FxCopReport Version="1.36" />
</FxCopProject>
```

Comment: I was looking for more in-depth filtering of rules. For example the rule CA1014 "Mark assemblies with CLSCompliantAttribute" in the Microsoft.Design rule set can be ignored. I was actually looking for a list of rules that can be ignored from each of the default FxCop rule sets which should result in the list of rules that the development community is generally using.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such beast.  And even if there was, how could you be sure that the decisions made by whoever created the list actually suit your situation?

There are only 200 or so rules.  Why not just sit down for an hour or two to figure out which ones you consider to be important?  You could even take a shortcut and just look at the ones that are currently giving you violations.  That would probably bring the screening effort down to less than 1/2 an hour.